# How can I merge two dictionaries where their trees have a matching key?

Tags: python

I'd like to merge these two dicts where they meet, on the "family" key. I'm working on a recursive function to make the merge happen but I wonder if there isn't a better way. I was looking at collections.chainmap and it seemed close that what I'm doing but perhaps overkill.

Input:

```
xe-3/0/2:
  description:
  unit:
    '0':
      family:
        inet4:
            address: 10.0.0.1
xe-3/0/2:
  description:
  unit:
    '0':
      family:
        inet6:
            address: FE80::
```

Output:

```
xe-3/0/2:
  description:
  unit:
    '0':
      family:
        inet4:
            address: 10.0.0.1
        inet6:
            address: FE80::
```

I'm trying to get better at python by using more tricks and built-in functions but I don't think I have the right approach for discovering what I can do instead of stacking a bunch of for loops.

Thanks,

EDIT:

This function works perfectly for my case, with the following assumptions:

D1 will always be deeper and wider.
D2 will always have a single tree.

```
def join_dicts(d1, d2):
  def recurse_join(d1, d2):
    if not isinstance(d1, dict) and not isinstance(d2, dict):
        return [d1, d2]
    if not isinstance(d1, dict):
        return {**{d1 : ""}, **d2}
    if not isinstance(d2, dict):
        return {**d1, **{d2 : ""}}

    for key in d2:
        if key not in d1:
            return {**d1, **d2}
        else:
            d1[key] = recurse_join(d1[key], d2[key])
    return d1
return recurse_join(d1, d2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use recursion with `collections.defaultdict`:

```
import yaml, collections
d1 = yaml.safe_load('''xe-3/0/2:
  description:
  unit:
    '0':
      family:
        inet4:
            address: 10.0.0.1''')
d2 = yaml.safe_load('''xe-3/0/2:
  description:
  unit:
    '0':
      family:
        inet6:
            address: FE80''')

def merge(*args):
   if any(not isinstance(i, dict) for i in args):
       return args[0] if len(args) == 1 else list(args)
   d = collections.defaultdict(list)
   for i in args:
      for a, b in i.items():
         d[a].append(b)
   return {a:merge(*b) for a, b in d.items()}

print(yaml.dump(merge(d1, d2)))
```

Output:

```
xe-3/0/2:
  description:
  unit:
    '0':
      family:
        inet4:
          address: 10.0.0.1
        inet6:
          address: FE80
```

Comment: Hey, I'm trying out this funtion and it works really nicely even in cases where the two dicts don't have the same depth.

However on the yaml.dump I keep seeing this `- !!python/tuple` tag and some stuff isn't nesting perfectly.

See this example: https://hastebin.com/azeresibaw.yaml

Comment: @MrPoulet `!!python/tuple` is how `yaml` alerts readers of the output that it had to interpret a Python object (in this case a `tuple`). I updated my answer to only use `dict`s/`list`s

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why recursion wouldn't work in this case - no libraries required.

```py
d1 = {
    "xe-3/0/2": {
        "description": {"unit": {"0": {"family": {"inet4": {"address": "10.0.0.1"}}}}}
    }
}
d2 = {
    "xe-3/0/2": {
        "description": {"unit": {"0": {"family": {"inet6": {"address": "FE80::"}}}}}
    }
}

def join_dicts(d1, d2):
    def recurse_join(d1, d2):
        # d1 must have greater depth than d2
        for key in d1:
            try:
                if not d2.get(key):
                    return {**d1, **d2}
            except AttributeError:
                return {**d1, **{d2: ""}}
            d1[key] = recurse_join(d1[key], d2[key])
            return d1
        
    def recurse_size(d, count=0):
        # Determines depth of dictionary.
        if not isinstance(d, dict):
            return count
        for key in d:
            return recurse_size(d[key], count+1)
    
    if recurse_size(d1) > recurse_size(d2):
        return recurse_join(d1, d2)
    return recurse_join(d2, d1)

print(join_dicts(d1, d2))
```

Will result in:

```
{
    "xe-3/0/2": {
        "description": {
            "unit": {
                "0": {
                    "family": {
                        "inet4": {"address": "10.0.0.1"},
                        "inet6": {"address": "FE80::"},
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is great. I've been toying around with this function for a while but it busts if d1 and d2 don't have the same depth.

For instance, I have a line where the value  of "family" is simply "iso".

Then, when it does : 
`return {**d1, **d2}`
   
It's doing
`return { {"family" : { lots of things}}, {"family" : "iso"}`

and it gets crunched into `"family" : "iso"`, and I lose the rest of the content.

Do you have any suggestions for handling this kind of case?

Comment: Thanks for the comment - if two dictionaries share similar keys like this but one is a dict and other not, would you want the non-dict value to become a dictionary with empty value? Please see updated answer.

Comment: I haven't decided yet. This is only the first half of a parser I'm writing and having empty dicts as values makes the second half useless. Ajax1234's version puts duplicate dead-ends in a list and I think that's the best compromise for now, at least.

Comment: Hey, I wasn't able to work on this last week but I finally got a version that works in every case.

https://hastebin.com/egakoyaqix.apache

The problem was that d1 will aggregate about 100 lines of these nested dictionaries. The recurse_size function is nice but only checks depth and not width. So if D1 has a shallow key that doesn't exist in D2, it assumes we're at the end of the tree and it merges everything. This would cause values to be lost.

There is one thing I didn't add in my original question.

D1 will always be bigger than D2.
D2 will always only have a single tree.

Comment: With these assumptions I was able to build on the function you gave me and got something that works for every case.

Answer (score 0):

```
You should be able to do this with just TWO for loops given your example data:

originalDict

dictToMergeIn


for key in dictToMergeIn do:
    var item = dictToMergeIn[key]
    if key in originalDict do:
        for inet in item[unit]['0'][family] do
            originalDict[key][unit]['0'][family][inet] = item[unit]['0'][family][inet] 
    else:
        originalDict[key] = item
```

I think you are right that you will need more for loops if you have multiple units, for example. Share what you've tried code wise if you want more help.

Answer (score 0):

#### With only recursion and simplest way.

With this method, there is no need to check which tree is the deepest.

Example datas:

```
d1 = {"tags": {"name1" : {"a1": {"e": 12}, "b1": 11}}, "constaints": {"name1": {"ml1": 10, "cl1": 110}}}

d2 = {"tags": {"name2" : {"a2": 2, "b2": 22}}, "constaints": {"name2": {"ml2": 20, "cl2": 220}}}
```

Code:

```
def join_dicts(d1, d2):

    rep = {k1: v1 for k1, v1 in d1.items()}  # Create a new dict to ensure to keep inputs unchanged

    for k2, v2 in d2.items():
    
        if k2 not in rep:
            rep[k2] = v2
        else:
            rep[k2] = join_dicts(rep[k2], v2)
        
    return rep
```